# SpriteKit - Touch moved, how to prevent node jump to touch location

Tags: sprite-kit

I wrote code for touch moved like this:

```
"override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        player.position = location"
```

The problem is the node/player will jump to wherever I touch and moved in the scene.
How may I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: you haven't said what your desired output is supposed to be

Comment: Sorry. I want the node to move along with my touch moves. For example, currently if I touch moved somewhere on the screen, the node will jump to that location and I don't want that. I try to use a variable to fix it but another problem is the node can be moved out of the screen. So another question is how can I keep the node within the screen wherever I touch moved it.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer this in pseudo code for two reasons, I am here to help you not do it for you and as a beginner figuring out how to do this yourself could be greatly beneficial.

```
var ball: SKSpriteNode!
var minWidth: CGFloat = 0
var maxWidth: CGFloat = 0
var startPosX: CGFloat = 0 
var startBallPosX: CGFloat = 0 

func didMove() {

    //did move func of the scene

    //setup ball and min and max widths

    ball = SKSpriteNode()
    addChild(ball)

    minWidth = scene.frame.minX
    maxWidth = scene.frame.maxY
}

func touchesBegan() {

    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    startPosX = location.x
    startBallPosX = ball.position.x
}

func touchesMoved() {

    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    var moveXValue = location.x - startPosX 

    if startBallPosX + moveXValue > maxWidth {
        //if ball wants to go past right edge of screen keep it at the edge
        ball.position.x = maxWidth 
    }
    else if startBallPosX + moveXValue < minWidth {
        //if ball wants to go past left edge of screen keep it at the edge
        ball.position.x = minWidth 
    }
    else {
        ball.position.x = startBallPosX + moveXValue
    }
}
```